# Loading datastore based on boolean flag

Tags: google-app-maker

I want to make a purchase order manager, where a queue is created from a database and then assembled into an accordion. Then, the user can look at requests, and then check the request when it is done. The task will then move to a "completed purchases" list.

I've been using a "notPurchased" datastore with the following server script:

```
query.filters.purchased._equals = false;
return query.run();
```

And then when the "submit" button is pressed, I call `datastore.load();`. However, this doesn't seem to refresh the purchase queue immediately. I have to completely refresh the page in order to see purchase request moved to 'completed'. How do I make this change instantaneous?

Comment: I had this problem too and got it resolved by unloading the datasource and loading it again. For example, when the submit button is pressed, you should call `datastore.unload();` and then `datastore.load();` I don't know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: datasource.load() ?

Comment: @Morfinismo I tried that and it didn't work. did you have any settings anywhere else that may have affected this?

Comment: Are you sure you are loading right datasource? Did you try to explicitly load datasource you need?: app.datasources.NotPurchased.load();

Comment: @PavelShkleinik That worked! Thank you! However, there is about a half-second delay where the screen is blank while it reloads datasources. any way to avoid that?

Comment: You can remove datasoarce.unload() and add loading indicator bound to @datasource.loading property. You can find this pattern in some of templates: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/

Comment: @PavelShkleinik Thanks a ton Pavel!

Comment: You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution that reduced any lag. Instead of filtering the database with a query, I bound the 'visibility' property to the proper boolean flag. Now items move instantly!